Метод экспорта в XML на сайте draw.io
Как получить строку xml которую сайт draw.io загружает при экспорте в  xml. При написании расширения для браузера появилась необходимость получить контент этого xml непосредственно через js код на самом сайте. Есть ли способ его получения?

Способ есть, но сразу хочу подчеркнуть потребуется единоразовое действие через меню (сохранение файла), если это не расходится с вашей задачей расширения, дайте знать.
